# Quartz JobStoreTX timeout expired

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET in a C# Windows service. The database it communicates with for persisted store data and other stuff lives on another machine in the same network running SQL Server 2008.

Every night I keep the service running and go home. When I come back in the morning, Quartz.NET is in a bad state. The first error is always a SQL timeout that happens around 6pm. <strike>This is odd, because the database is near idle by that time, and Quartz's constant pinging wouldn't give the connection a chance to expire or whatever:</strike> (**EDIT:** See below for new details.)

```
2014-10-29 18:22:04,435 [InfoSnapScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] WARN  Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreTX [(null)] – ConnectionAndTransactionHolder passed to RollbackConnection was null, ignoring
2014-10-29 18:22:04,435 [InfoSnapScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR Quartz.Core.ErrorLogger [(null)] – An error occurred while scanning for the next trigger to fire.
Quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failure setting up connection. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginSqlTransaction(IsolationLevel iso, String transactionName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.System.Data.IDbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
   at Quartz.Impl.AdoJobStore.JobStoreSupport.GetConnection() in c:\Work\OpenSource\quartznet\src\Quartz\Impl\AdoJobStore\JobStoreSupport.cs:line 380
```

After that it constantly cycles the WARN in line 1.

I'm not *as* concerned about the timeout error - database goofs happen. I'll assume Quartz isn't to blame there. But I need to be able to recover from these errors and keep Quartz in a good state to keep pinging, albeit after waiting. Is there anything I can override or modify to capture an error when checking triggers?

Alternative question: how can this `ConnectionAndTransactionHolder` problem be fixed/prevented?

**EDIT:** The server admin shared with me that the database does replication work four times a day, including - wait for it! - 6p. I'll assume this is the cause. The original question remains of how to recover from the errors it spawns.

Comment: Can you share your config file?

Comment: @CircularReference: A heavily sanitised version, perhaps. If the reason you want to see it is regarding the timeout itself, that matter has been settled. See edits.

Comment: What is the value for "quartz.jobstore.misfirethreshold"?

Comment: @CircularReference: 60000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the ConnectionAndTransactionHolder message isn't actually an error: in Quartz.NET 2.3 it will be logged as INFO. After the heightened anxiety this message caused, I'm thinking Quartz was never actually in a bad state. (At the time my code was in a worse state than the service itself -- maybe that's what I was suffering through!) Indeed, it seems fine after a night of running.

I did, however, file a ticket on GitHub asking for Quartz to ping the database less often when it's down.